# Automapper: same instance after mapping

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I try Automapper and it is very nice but is it possible map two OuterDto source to OuterModel destination with same object InnerDeto like in code? How can I do that dest1.Inner and dest2.Inner after map has same instance? What I know, I think it is not possible. What do you think? Thanks for help me

```
    public class OuterDto
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public InnerDto Inner { get; set; }

    }

    public class InnerDto
    {
        public int OtherValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class OuterModel
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public InnerModel Inner { get; set; }

    }

    public class InnerModel
    {
        public int OtherValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class test
    {
        public test()
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<InnerDto, InnerModel>().ReverseMap();
                cfg.CreateMap<OuterDto, OuterModel>().ReverseMap();
            });
            config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

            InnerDto innerSource = new InnerDto { OtherValue = 15 };
            var source1 = new OuterDto
            {
                Value = 1,
                Inner = innerSource
            };
            var source2 = new OuterDto
            {
                Value = 2,
                Inner = innerSource
            };
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            source1.Inner.OtherValue = 20;
            var dest1 = mapper.Map<OuterDto, OuterModel>(source1);
            var dest2 = mapper.Map<OuterDto, OuterModel>(source2);
            dest1.Inner.OtherValue = 1000;

            //Result:
            //dest1.Inner.OtherValue = 1000
            //dest2.Inner.OtherValue = 20

            //Expected Result:
            //dest1.Inner.OtherValue = 1000
            //dest2.Inner.OtherValue = 1000


        }
    }
```

Comment: How would AutoMapper know when to reuse a single instance? Because they have the same `Value`?

Comment: The setting is called `PreserveReferences`.

Comment: PreserveReferences is for circular reference in one class rigth?

Comment: How about you try it in your example? :)

Comment: I tried it before created post. Here is code https://dotnetfiddle.net/Spn4nK but same result.

Comment: The references are kept per map operation. I thought that was obvious :) So map the objects together, as an array maybe?

Comment: Like use source[] instead source1 and source2? https://dotnetfiddle.net/nXLnUy That also not working

Comment: If I were you I'd take another look at that code :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not know what you mean. Cout you tell me more detail please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but try to instanciate `OuterModel` before calling `Map` method

```cs
            //...
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            source1.Inner.OtherValue = 20;

            var dest1 = new OuterModel();
            mapper.Map(source1, dest1);
            mapper.Map(source2, dest1);
            dest1.Inner.OtherValue = 1000;
```

NOTE: I haven't tested my code, it's just to give food for thought

Comment: This would make the outer models be the same instance, not just the inner as requested by the OP.